# Playwright how to wait for locator that matches multiple elements to not be visible

Tags: node.js, playwright

I am trying to wait for an element that indicates a page is still loading, and exists on the page multiple time, to not be visible (think table with loading data placeholders).

Playwright documentation suggests using Locators is best practice, and therefore I initially tried to achieve this by doing:

```
locator.waitFor({state: "hidden")
```

However that errors due to Locators being strict and only being allow to match one element.

I'm now doing it with the following code:

```
page.waitForSelector(".foo .bar", {state: "hidden"})
```

This is non-ideal for a couple of reasons:

- I'm storing page elements as locators in the Page Object Model, and you seemingly cannot access the selector of a locator, meaning the selector is duplicated in the code
- I believe page.waitForSelector will use an ElementHandle which is discouraged

Is there any way to turn off the strictness constraint on a Locator? Or a way to achieve this using the Locator. I'm aware you can do `.count` on a Locator which matches multiple elements, but I've not found a nice way to combine that with waiting for the count to be 0.

Comment: So using https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#lists and awaiting the visible state on each locator does not work for you?

Comment: @madflow ah no I'd glanced past that in the docs and not appreciated what that was for! I've got a working solution now (looping round getting the hidden state of all elements and waiting till they are all true, or a timeout is exceeded).

Comment: Simple one liner solution- https://stackoverflow.com/a/75854361

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working in the end using the `evaluateAll` method. Example code:

```js
async waitForAllHidden(locator: Locator, timeout: number = 10000) {
    const start = Date.now()
    const elementsVisible = async () => (
        await locator.evaluateAll(elements =>
            elements.map(element => element.hidden))
    ).includes(false)

    while (await elementsVisible()) {
        if (start + timeout < Date.now()) {
            throw (`Timeout waiting for all elements to be hidden.
                    Locator: ${locator}. Timeout: ${timeout}ms`);
        }
    }
    console.log(`All elements hidden: ${locator}`)
}
```

### Update for 2023:

There are new methods available which can now be used for this purpose:

[toHaveCount()](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-count)
e.g.

```js
await expect(yourLocator).toHaveCount(0);
```

[poll()](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#expectpoll)
e.g.

```js
await expect.poll(async () => {
  for (const e of await yourLocator.all()) {
    if (await e.isVisible()) return false
  }
  return true
}, {
  message: 'youLocator is still visible', // optional custom error message
  intervals: [1_000, 2_000, 10_000], // optional polling overrides
  timeout: 10000, // optional timeout override
}).toBe(true);
```

Comment: This is a bit convoluted solution for an simpler problem.

Comment: Agreed, but at the time there wasn't a better solution

Comment: This is not a recommended solution. There's no need to write custom timeouts or loops in Playwright if you use its API properly, like `poll()` or `toPass()`, even if `toHaveCount()` was not available. I suggest moving the checkmark to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75854361/6243352) and considering deletion.

Comment: `poll()` (added in v1.21.0) and `toPass()` (added in v1.29.0) were also not available when I wrote this question. Bear in mind that features available to you now in Playwright have not always been there. I have updated the answer with current methods.

Answer (score 3):

hope it will work

this code will check the next element each time the previous one disappears

```
while (await page.locator('.foo .bar').first().isVisible()) { //do nothing }
```

Comment: This could get you stuck in an infinite loop if they never stop being visible. I've got a working solution now using `evaluateAll` function.

Comment: This solution works as well, to avoid infinite loop timeout can be passed in the function call.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal In which function call?

Comment: @bee-anchor while(await expect(page.locator(locator)).not.toBeVisible({timeout: 2000 })) {  }

Comment: There's no need for the `while` loop in Playwright assertions. The loop here is basically a confusing no-op since if the locator assertion throws, the loop will not repeat. Assertions are not booleans that you can test in conditions like this--they throw if they fail.

Answer (score 3):

> Spinner or an "..loading" text element's presence cannot be verified
> for sure as it may or may not appear during page load depending on
> page performance .

> *However , it's *eventual disappearance* can be verified.*

Use [toHaveCount()](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-count) (Added in: v1.20)

```
await expect(locator).toHaveCount(0,{timeout:5000});
```

**Timeout**:
To avoid infinite loops timeout can be configured globally or passed as an parameter in the  function call.

```
// playwright.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';

export default defineConfig({
  expect: {
    timeout: 5000
  },
});
```

**Tip**: Its better to keep local timeouts lower than global timeout to avoid any race conditions if both exist.

Reference: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/11988

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74209034/1831456

[How can I assert that an element is NOT on the page in playwright?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71183099/how-can-i-assert-that-an-element-is-not-on-the-page-in-playwright/73214414#73214414)