# How can I assert that an element is NOT on the page in playwright?

Tags: typescript, playwright

I'm testing a website that includes a logo, and I want to make sure the logo does not appear on some pages.

How can I assert that an element does NOT exist?  I checked the [Playwright assertions documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/assertions), but it only has examples of checking for things that do exist.

```
async assertNoLog(): Promise<boolean> {
  await this.page.locator('div#page-id'); // now the page has loaded
  // How do I check if logo is on page without throwing an error if it is missing
}
```

I'm not sure what to write here to assert that my element is not found anywhere on the page.

Comment: I think its important to differentiate  here that  logo may attach to the page DOM as element but just should not be visible for the requirement to begin with , NOT until its gone.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To check it instantly without auto-waiting, you can use `count()` and assert that it returns 0.

```
expect(await page.locator('.notexists').count()).toEqual(0);
```

If you want Playwright to wait until the count becomes 0 (as recommended by web-first assertions) then you should await the expect and use `toHaveCount()`

```
await expect(page.locator('.notexists')).toHaveCount(0);
```

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-count
https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-count

Comment: For me, `count()` times out! What is it possibly waiting for?

Comment: I was missing an `await`. (Still weird.)

Comment: My Visual Studio Code puts 3 little dots to highlight unnecessary awaits so that makes it easy to delete them.  Then I can just add "await" to the beginning of pretty much everything.

Comment: Great idea! I've managed to set up the [`no-floating-promises`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-floating-promises/) ESLint rule now.

Comment: [Erik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74209034/72321) is now preferred; follows Playwright guidelines on using [web first assertions](https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#use-web-first-assertions).

Comment: @DanielDarabos without an await then it was returning a promise instead of a value and expecting the promise to equal zero.  I would think that it should just fail the assertion but if the timing gets messed up sometimes that expresses itself as a timeout instead

Comment: The `await` should be before expect to follow playwright guideline of web first assertion https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#use-web-first-assertions. So it should be 
`await expect(page.locator('.notexists')).toEqual(0);` or `await expect(page.locator('.notexists')).toHaveCount(0);`something like this. 
This is not exactly right but somewhere along the lines that `await` should be before `expect`.

Comment: I disagree, @utkarsh-k.  There's nothing in the playwright best practices doc that says you should have an unnecessary await before an expect.  Web first assertions are an unrelated topic.

Comment: @emery Please read the link in utkarsh-k's comment. The [docs show](https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#use-web-first-assertions): `await expect(page.getByText('welcome')).toBeVisible(); // ` and `expect(await page.getByText('welcome').isVisible()).toBe(true); // ` which is pretty clear. The `await` outside the `expect` is not unnecessary, it's a web-first assertion that auto-waits for the condition to become true. This is the standard assertion in Playwright and is relevant here. I suggest modifying this answer to clarify that it's not the standard assertion.

Comment: I have updated my answer as per comments by Dennis, ggorlen and @utkarsh-k

Answer (score 28):

I wanted to know that an element wasn't on screen, but I also wanted to *wait* until it was gone, and this is the way to do that:

```js
await expect(locator).toHaveCount(0);
```

[Found here](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/11988)

Comment: Unlike `await expect(locator).not.toBeAttached()`, this works regardless of whether you're going from 3 elements down to 0, or from 1 element down to 0. Use `await expect(locator).not.toBeAttached()` if you want that implicit single element assertion guarantee. Both idioms are useful in different contexts.

Answer (score 11):

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-be-attached

> toBeAttached
>
> Added in: v1.33
>
> Ensures that Locator points to an attached DOM node.

With this, now we can do:

```
expect(locator).not.toBeAttached()
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - clean and with no magic constants like zero in "toHaveCount(0)"

Comment: @Dušan I agree this probably is better, but generally speaking, 0 isn't exactly a magic constant under the traditional definition. It's not subject to change and always means 0. For example, writing `for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {}` does not use "magic constants" any more than this does. One potentially useful feature in the `toHaveCount(0)` approach is that it doesn't fail if the count goes from 3 to 0, whereas this only handles 1 to 0.

Comment: @JohnSpencer don't forget to `await expect(locator).not.toBeAttached()`.

Comment: Personally prefer closer to the user assertions like tobevisible. But good idea too.

Answer (score 6):

You could try using `not` before `toBeVisible` assertion on the routes you don't want it to be.

```js
async assertNoLog(): Promise<boolean> {
  await this.page.locator('div#page-id'); // now the page has loaded

  // Check if the logo is on the page without throwing an error if it is missing
await expect(page.locator('div#page-id')).not.toBeVisible();
}
```

It's recommended to use more direct assertions when available:

```js
await expect(page.locator('div#page-id')).toBeHidden();
```

Check: https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices

Answer (score 3):

You can play with the conditions you expect your element to have. For example, at Playwright's homepage you expect an element by the class .navbar__brand to be visible, but you also expect an element by the class .notexists NOT to be visible (in this case this element would not exist). Then you can do:

```js
test('element does exist @pass', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');
  const locator = await page.locator('.navbar__brand').isVisible();
  expect(locator).toBeTruthy();
});

test('element does NOT exist @fail', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');
  const locator = await page.locator('.notexists').isVisible();
  expect(locator).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Doing this, of course, would return the same results:

```js
test('element does exist @pass', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');
  expect(await page.locator('.navbar__brand').isVisible()).toBe(true);
});

test('element does NOT exist @fail', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');
  expect(await page.locator('.notexists').isVisible()).toBe(true);
});
```

As I say, the element's conditions are up to you. For example, if you want to assert an element with visibility:hidden is also not present in the DOM, because it simply shouldn't be, you can wrap the visibility and a .isHidden() conditions within a if/else, etc. And of course, feel free to play with booleans (toBe(true)/toBe(false), toBeTruthy()/toBeFalsy()).

These are not the most elegant solutions out there, but I hope they can help.

Comment: I was tempted to downvote this because it's not a very elegant solution as compared to using count() but it does provide some very useful information.

Comment: Warning: this doesn't use [web-first assertions](https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#use-web-first-assertions).

Answer (score 2):

You could also use Locator#waitFor method with 'detached' state. The benefit is that is also waits for some time for element state to change. It is helpful if detaching an element from DOM takes some time.

https://playwright.dev/docs/next/api/class-locator#locator-wait-for

Example:

```
await page.locator('someSelector').waitFor({ state: "detached" })
```

Other states allow for verification whether an element is visible / hidden

Answer (score 0):

Another way using Chai assertions is using the "**!**" symbol before the element:

```
should.exist(!your selector here)
```